# BindingSource.Filter from DataGridView without datasource

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, datasource, bindingsource

I am using `BindingSource` in filtering my `DataGridView` records. Now, our team decided to add rows manually to the table instead of adding a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`. Using `DataSource` to populate the `DataGridView` I used the following code in filtering records:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dgv.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "[ColumnName] like '%" + keyword + "%'";
dgv.DataSource = bs;
```

When I use the same code, the `DataSource` is turning out to be `null`. How will I apply `BindingSource` filter without having a `DataSource`?

Comment: Does the original `DataGridView` …`dgv`… have a `DataTable` as a DataSource?

Comment: @JohnG No it doesn't.

Comment: If there is no data source for the `DataGridView` `dgv`, then the line `bs.DataSource = dgv.DataSource;` will obviously return null. I am not sure how you would filter a `DataSource` that DNE. How is `dgv` getting filled originally? Without a data source you may have to filter the data yourself. If this happens, then I would consider making my own data source from the grid itself. I question why your team would decide to remove the data source from the grid without considering the consequences of removing this data source.

Comment: This will inevitably create a lot of work to simply maintain the data in the `DatGridView`. Work that a `DataSource` not only does for you conveniently but is designed just for this kind of maintenance and filtering. I am guessing it may be easier for you to make your own data source from the grid. I am not aware of any filtering properties of the `DataGridView` itself.